# Xcodeを使った集団開発の進め方を教えてください

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

法人でApple　Developper Programに申請及び承認されました。

Xcodeを使用して、複数のエンジニアでアプリを開発、リリース予定なのですが、やり方を知りたいです。

Swiftで集団開発をするにはgitなどが必要になってくるのでしょうか？
実務経験がなく、イメージがわきません。

大まかな流れや、おすすめサイトを教えてください。

Comment: Xcodeに限らずチーム開発の経験がない人材のみで何かアプリをリリースしたいということでしょうか？どの程度のスキルや経験年数をもったメンバーがいるかという情報も書いてもらった方がアドバイスする側もしやすくなると思います。

Comment: マルチポストお疲れさまです https://teratail.com/questions/204380

Comment: 煽るような書き方はやめましょう。マルチポストを行う際はその旨を明言した方が良いです。推奨はしていませんが禁止はされていないかと思います。ただし、teratail側では利用規約に禁止事項としてあったような気がします。[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/)

Answer (score 3):

https://teratail.com/questions/204380
でも回答があります（マイナス評価もついています）が

- 管理体制があること
  １つのプロジェクトを完成させるにはプログラマだけではなくてシナリオライタ、デザイナ、イラストレータ、テストプレイヤー、声優、音楽担当、マニュアルライター、翻訳担当など種類の違う仕事がいっぱい必要です。となるとその取りまとめができる人が必要です（俗にいう偉い人）。プログラマだけ集まって仕事できると思っていたら大間違い、その辺の人財（人は財産）が揃っていないなら手を出すには早すぎです。
- 手戻りをなくすシステムがあること
  大規模プロジェクトでは必然的に分業になるので、手戻りがあると「直した→直ってない！」を繰り返して前に進みません。これをなくすシステムが必要です。

これらの一環として [git](/questions/tagged/git) や [redmine](/questions/tagged/redmine) がどーこうとかそういう話ができるようになります。まずは開発できる体制があるかを自問してください。